# Benefits of factoring matrix multiplication into two matrix multiplications?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning, neural-networks

Assuming we have a linear transformation for vectors $\in \mathbb{R}^n$ to vectors $\in \mathbb{R}^m$ denoted $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{W} \mathbf{x}$ and that the goal is to learn the values of $\mathbf{W}$ (or at least the values that produce minimum loss)  from data.

My question is as follows:

Is there any benefit from splitting the linear transformation to two matrices and learning the factors  instead of learning the original one, i.e.,  if $\mathbf{W} = \mathbf{AB}$, then learn $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ instead of learning $\mathbf{W}$? Are there any mathematical properties of such factoring that make it useful?

Unfortunately, I am unable to find a mathematical term for this matrix factorization (if this is a proper term to use), so it would be great if someone can tell me what should I be reading about.

Also, the only benefit I could find is that if $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times q}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times n}$ and $q < n$, the number of parameters needed would be $(n + m) \times q$ instead of $n \times m$.

Comment: There are many ways to factor a matrix. Is there a specific factorization that you’re asking about?

Comment: Not really, I am just asking for the benefit of learning such factors instead of learning the original matrix.

Comment: Here's a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization.

Comment: @AdrianKeister can you put that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I'd love to, but it's only one look at the answer, and a single link is not considered a good answer on M.SE. Glad it was helpful, though!

Comment: If you want more answers you need to add more structure - you haven't put any probabilistic structure into the set up, or much at all in the way of the model apart from a 'neural-networks' tag for no obvious reason?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are lots of pro:s of doing that. Finding good factorizations can lead to more efficient algorithms in natural sciences and engineering. Maybe one of the most famous ones, the [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) ( Fast Fourier Transform ) can indeed be interpreted as a matrix factorization.

The original matrix is dense ( has no values equal to $0$, but in the FFT factorization each row of each factor matrix has only a small prime number of non-zero entries, usually $2$ non-zero values and there is only $\log_2(N)$ such matrix factors.

Now the FFT is factoring more than once and into more than two matrices, but this can be done step-by-step in a systematic fashion where each step splits one matrix into two.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, this is a very specific case, and I am more interested in a more general case. But, thank you, I have read about it and it really benefited me.